# Passing XMLDocument as parameter to XSLT

Tags: .net, xslt

I would like to pass the XMLdocument itself as parameter to the XSLT (without saving the XML physically). Is there any way to do that. My function accepts two Xmldocument and need to create new XML based on the two XML.

Comment: When you say 'parameter', do you mean a parameter to the .NET method, or a parameter to the XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: its a parameter to XSLT which i pass using XSLTarguments. I want to access the XMLDocument in XSLT. Here i use multiple XML to create a single XML. All the XML's are coming as parameter of type XMLDocument to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform accepts an XmlReader; you can create an XmlNodeReader (which suffices) for any element in your DOM (typically the document element).

Comment: @i0707 I can add some examples later if you like but more or less like the example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx but passing a `new XmlNodeReader(rootNode)` for the source object

Comment: I tried as below, but it doesn't working                    XmlDocument testXml = new XmlDocument(); testXml.Load(@"D:\search.xml");                                   XmlNode xmlNode = testXml.SelectSingleNode("response"); XmlNodeReader xmlNodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode);  arguments.AddParam("SearchXml", "", xmlNodeReader);

Comment: @i0707 I'm on mobile at the moment - I'll try to add an example later

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off just combining your xml document nodes and transforming on the entire thing.  There are ways to pass xml in as parameters but none of them are pretty and after you do it, you're still going to be forced to so some xsl trickery to gain access to it.