# XSLT eliminating specified elements in XML file

Tags: xslt

I have a follwing XML file:

```
<guests>  
   <guest roomnumber="111" email="john.perry@abc.com"/>  
   <guest roomnumber="112" email="JohnMarconi@lema.fr"/>
   <guest roomnumber="114" email="John_kim@kema.nl"/>
   <guest roomnumber="127" email="jim.taylor@sat.com"/>
   <guest roomnumber="133" email="Jane.Doe@abc.com"/>  
   <guest roomnumber="135" email="janesullivan@ati.org"/>
   <guest roomnumber="136" email="Albert.Jones@lec.org"/>   
</guests>
```

and would like to eliminate the elements with @email starting with 'john' or 'jane', performing case-insensitive name search.

The resulting XML file should like like this:

```
<guests>  
   <guest roomnumber="127" email="jim.taylor@sat.com"/>
   <guest roomnumber="136" email="Albert.Jones@lec.org"/>   
</guests>
```

In the transformation I would like to use a parameter "Name", such as

```
   <xsl:param name="Name"> 
        <x>john</x> 
        <x>jane</x> 
    </xsl:param>
```

or

```
 <xsl:param name="Name" select="'john,jane'" />
```

How could such a transfomation be implemented using XSLT 1.0? Alas, in my case XSLT 2.0 and the document() function are not supported.

TIA, Leo

Comment: `<guest roomnumber="125" email="John&Jane@lec.org"/>` is neither well-formed XML nor is it even a valid email address. Please use actual data in samples or at least take some care when making them up.

Comment: @Leo68 Here's a proof of concept http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/WjC6xC regarding my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you pass in the `$name` parameter as an *actual XML document* (i.e., you don't define it in the XSLT document, because that would produce a [result tree fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments), which is not readily usable without an extension function):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:if test="
      not(self::guest)
      or
      not($Name/x[starts-with(translate(current()/@email, $upper, $lower), .)])
    ">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you pass in `$name` as a comma-delimited list of strings, things will get *a lot* more complicated, so I suggest you try passing an XML document first.

---

**EDIT:** Here is a version of the same thing that uses an inline definition of the names and `node-set()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

  <xsl:param name="Name"> 
    <x>john</x> 
    <x>jane</x> 
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="Excluded" select="exsl:node-set($Name)/x" />

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:if test="
      not(self::guest)
      or
      not($Excluded[starts-with(translate(current()/@email, $upper, $lower), .)])
    ">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello Tomalak, Thanks for your suggestion. As I mentinoned in my question, I cannot use the document() function. I have no problems with using extension functions. So it would be interesting to see the full transformation with an inline xsl parameter, if possible.

Comment: @Leo My solution does not use the `document()` function. I'm not sure what you mean. It would be nice if you gave some info about the environment you're in (host programming language, where does the contents of `$Name` come from, etc).

Comment: Host programming language is C#; the best option for me is to define $Name parameter inline; XSLT 2.0 and the document() function are not supported; using extension functions is OK. If you could post the full XSLT, which eliminates the specified elements using the inline $Name parameter, it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: @Leo: With C# you can provide parameters that are actual XML types. That's what I'm talking about. Neither defining the parameter value "inline" nor passing a string is necessary. Same for extension functions or `document()`. Pass a list of `<x>` elements to the processor in form of an `XmlReader` object. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6983176/18771. If you positively *must* use an inline definition, use `exsl:node-set()`. See http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000714.html

Comment: @ Tomalak: So how your full XSLT will look like using exsl:node-set()?

Comment: @Leo: Just switch `$Name` with `exsl:node-set($Name)`

Comment: @ Tomalak: Also after switching $Name with exsl:node-set($Name) it does not work. Perhaps, if you could post the full XSLT which would yield the wanted result after applying on the provided XML document, it would be easier to check the applicability of your method.

Comment: @Leo What's the good reason *not* to feed the XML nodes directly as a parameter from within C#? Surely you do not want to change your XSLT every time the list of names changes?

Comment: @ Tomalak: I do not have any problems with updating the list of names in XSLT and actually using the inline xsl parameter would be the preferred option. But as long as the working transformation is not posted it is difficult to judge if your approach is correct.

Comment: @Leo: Well, here you go, see changed answer. I don't think it would have been that difficult to figure it out on your own. Oleg Tkachenko's blog post I liked to above contains all the information you would have needed.

Comment: @ Tomalak: Thanks for this update. The XSLT is now working as expected and yields the desired results. I do not have much experience in this field, so it was very kind of you to help me to solve this problem and to explain some important aspects in this regard.

Comment: @Leo: That's all-right, you are welcome. Oh, and don't mistake me as being grumpy, I'm just rather direct. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you might try something along those lines:

**EDIT**
As Tomalak pointed out, you need to convert the `RTF` (result tree fragment) with the non-standard `xxx:node-set()` function!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
     exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxsl">

    <xsl:variable name="lower">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="upper">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/guests">
        <guests>
            <xsl:call-template name="foo">
                <xsl:with-param name="guests" select="guest"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="terms">
                    <x>John</x>
                    <x>jane</x>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </guests>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="foo">
        <xsl:param name="guests"/>
        <xsl:param name="terms"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$guests">
            <xsl:call-template name="bar">
                <xsl:with-param name="guest" select="."/>
                <!-- HERE ARE THE EDITED LINES -->
                <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="ext:node-set($terms)/*"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="runs" select="count(ext:node-set($terms)/*)"/>
                <!-- HERE ARE THE EDITED LINES -->
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="bar">
        <xsl:param name="runs" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="guest"/>
        <xsl:param name="prefix"/>

        <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(translate($guest/@email, $upper, $lower), translate($prefix, $upper, $lower)))">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$runs = 1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$guest"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="bar">
                       <xsl:with-param name="guest" select="$guest"/>
                       <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$prefix[not(position()=1)]"/>
                       <xsl:with-param name="runs" select="$runs - 1"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>               
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `$terms` will be an RTF, thus you cannot use its contents without resorting to `node-set()`.

Comment: @ aefxx Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will need to investigate this approach further. Do you think that using several parameters in the specified templates is the optimal way to solve the problem in question?

Comment: @Leo68 Well, that largely depends on the assumed amount of names to check against. I'd say that a list of half a dozen names could be concatenated into a single string param, sure, but anything beyond that is error-prone and I wouldn't want to maintain a list like this.

Comment: @Leo68 That said, if you do NOT want to use `node-set()` a concatenated string would work as well. You would have to fiddle with `substring-before()` and s `substring-after()` to split your names apart, though.

Comment: @aefxx Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions and explanations.

Comment: @Leo68 You're welcome. Did learn about RTF this way. Win-win situation, hehe.